# Individual parameter tables vs wrapping them into a single table, which is better?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, architecture, schema

I've got various settings that need to be looked up and stored according to various parameters.

For example, I need to know the hardware settings, which depend on the computer being used and the type of device connected to the computer.

I need to know which the procedures to run, which depend on the device connected to the computer and the type of session.

I need to know how to process the data, which depends on the device, the type of session, and the computer.

| Setting (Item that can be looked up) | Parameter (what the setting depends on) |
| --- | --- |
| hardware settings | device, computer |
| procedures | device, session type |
| data processing | device, computer, session type |

In reality there are a lot more settings, and there are potentially more parameters that they would depend on, but the concept is this: there is some mix and match of parameters that can be used to look up settings.

This following is the obvious (and in my eyes naive) solution. Only relevant columns have been included:

[image]

This has various problems:

- Adding a new parameter requires all settings relevant tables to be updated.
- Lots of duplication of columns (e.g. lots of tables will have a DeviceId column and a SessionTypeId column)

My thinking is this: Why not wrap the parameters into a single table? Then settings can point to the wrapper table. If the settings don't depend on all the parameters they can point to wrapper records where the parameter is `NULL`:

[image]

Is there anything inherently problematic about this revised schema? What are the pros and cons of each approach? Which schema would you be more likely to use and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case for the KISS principle.

Only dozens or hundreds of devices, computers, procs, etc?  Skip the ids.  Simply use the unique name you already have for them.

Then, it might be simply one table with three columns:

- The computer/device/whatever
- Whether the value is a size/proc/etc
- The value/name/etc of one size/proc/etc.

Numbers can simply be stored as strings (`VARCHAR(191)`) so that there are no typing problems.  The program reading, say, a numeric "size", can simply treat the result as a number.

If one computer is allowed to run 3 procedures, then there would be 3 rows for that.

Comment: Im talking hundreds of devices and computers, etc each of which will have hundreds of settings records associated to each of them. Skipping the ids is absolutely not an option. Also, varchar(191) is definitely not happening for numbers, although that doesn't seem relevant here.

By the way, this is a massively dumbed-down abstraction of the actual database schema. I'm designing software to control an entire factory.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Barmar's answer of 9 years ago is reasonable.  `ids` should be `INT` (4 bytes) or some smaller int-type (eg, 2-byte `SMALLINT`).  Moving the string into the main table cause bloat.  I started my answer with "... dozens or hundreds ..."; this was to imply that if there aren't many rows, "bloat" is not a big deal.  You countered with "hundreds", so my answer may produce more bloat than you like.  So, don't use my answer.